# Why does the font-size of an input breaks the inline-block alignment?

Tags: html, css, input

I recently stumble over the problem where I had to align to inputs next to each other which had slightly different font-size parameter. It turns out that is breaks the alignment of the input elements.

Here an exaggerated example to show the problem:

```css
div input {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 34px;
}
.field1 {
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input class="field1" type="text" value="test">
  <input class="field2" type="text" value="test">
</div>
```

**What is the best way to fix that?** How do I align the two input elements in one line next to each other?

Comment: You'd want to research line-height and baseline for a more in depth explanation in all of the fun involved in font metrics. But, if you look at where the bottom of both words are, you can see they line up. There are many ways of fixing this, depending on how you want the result to look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vertical-align: top;` seems to help solve this problem. I added only that rule which will align the input elements to the top of its parent container (the `div` in this case).

```css
div input {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 34px;
  vertical-align: top; /* added */
}
.field1 {
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input class="field1" type="text" value="test">
  <input class="field2" type="text" value="test">
</div>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: I have added more of an explanation, thanks for letting me know. @MikeMcCaughan

Comment: @Kyle actually its seems to the right answer. Just asking my self why I didn't come up with it... ;-)

Comment: I believe it has something to do with how line-height, and perhaps margin and padding, works on fonts of different sizes. Take a look at this article which goes in depth about fonts and CSS: https://iamvdo.me/en/blog/css-font-metrics-line-height-and-vertical-align

Comment: @Kyle thanks for the link. Still interesting how the inner of the input influences the outside...